# Regular expression describing a three alphabet language with no occurrence of word where all three characters appear in a specific order

Tags: regex, regular-language, computation-theory

I am struggling to grasp the concept of describing a regular expression for a 3 alphabet language where the only restriction is on all three characters appearing in one specific order.

eg1 :
Write a regular expression over \S = {a, b, c} which ensures that w is such that there is **no occurrence** of the string "abc"

Valid matches include {bac, baac, cad, aaaaccb, abababac} the only word that should not be produced is "abc"

eg2 :
Write a regular expression over \S = {x, y, z} which ensures that w is such that there is **no occurrence** of the string "zyx"

Valid matches include {xyz, xyyx, yzx, zzyyxc, xyxyxzyzy} the only word that should not be produced is "zyx"

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? Also, a few matching and non-matching examples would be helpful.

Comment: Agreed, your question is unclear.

Comment: @PeterThoeny I hope that the edit has made the question clearer.

Answer (score 1):

We can make a DFA first and then run the algorithm to make the regular expression.

A DFA for the first is:

```
q      s        q'
----------------
q0    b,c     q0
q0    a        q1
q1    a        q1
q1    b        q2
q1    c        q0
q2    a        q1
q2    b        q0
q2    c        q3
q3    a,b,c  q3
```

We can write some equations...

```
q0 = q0(b + c) + q1c + q2b
q1 = q0a + q1a + q2a
q2 = q1b
```

We can replace all instances of q2 with q1b ...

```
q0 = q0(b + c) + q1(c + bb)
q1 = q0a + q1(a + ba)
q2 = q1b
```

We can remove the recursion in the equation for q1:

```
q0 = q0(b + c) + q1(c + bb) + e
q1 = q0a(a + ba)*
q2 = q1b
```

Now replace the expression for q1 ...

```
q0 = q0((b + c) + a(a + ba)*(c + bb)) + e
q1 = q0a(a + ba)*
q2 = q1b
```

Removing the recursion from the equation for q0 gives:

```
q0 = ((b + c) + a(a + ba)*(c + bb))*
q1 = q0a(a + ba)*
q2 = q1b
```

Filling in the others gives

```
q0 = ((b + c) + a(a + ba)*(c + bb))*
q1 = ((b + c) + a(a + ba)*(c + bb))*a(a + ba)*
q2 = ((b + c) + a(a + ba)*(c + bb))*a(a + ba)*b
```

Since these three states are accepting, our RE should be the union:

```
r = ((b + c) + a(a + ba)*(c + bb))*(e + a(a + ba)*(e + b))
```

Your other example is quite similar.